# Short story where a grandmother is living a few days ahead in time and a flood

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, prophecy

Young teen has a grandmother who is seen as crazy, she talks to people who aren't there and moves around the house miming different tasks to air.

The teen sees her grandma talking about a birthday party and doing something birthday related but specific. Then a few days later its her birthday and that specific situation happens and she starts to think her grandma isn't crazy.

Soon after, her grandma freaks out and is clinging to the bed post shrieking about water until she passes out and doesn't move. The teen finds out (has a prophetic dream?) that 3 days from now, the dam above the valley her family lives in will break and kill everyone, so her grandma experiences time a few days ahead and 'died' in that flood.

Story ends with the girl leaving her family to save herself because she knows they'd never believe her and she grapples with her 'gift' and thinks she might end up like her grandma.

This was probably read 8-12 years ago.

Comment: Sounds familiar. Connie Willis? Ursula Le Guin?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I've been trying to find this story too. Read it 7th grade in 2000. Don't remember much. Her grandmother was yelling at a wall which later became the den. The last line of the story was something like "there's one name grandma didn't yell" implying that it was hers and she was gone when the flood came and killed everyone.

Comment: @Nicki Unfortunately I have not found it, thank you for keeping the dream alive though XD. Didnt expect this specific story to resonate with anyone. Thought maybe I dreamed it for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posed [this question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/kwiq11/tomtshort_story90s_story_about_an_bedridden/), and someone found the answer. The story is part of a short story collection called [*Darkness Creeping: Twenty Twisted Tales*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?322286) by Neal Shusterman. The short story that we were both remembering is called "[Screaming at the Wall](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1134859)".

Comment: Could you [edit] to also explain how it matches the description in the question?

Comment: This is definitely the right story; the only element that doesn't match is the granddaughter doesn't display any evidence of precognition, it's just deduced from what her grandma says.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never would have found it. Mystery solved!